# What are com.[username].[api]? and how are they hosted?

Tags: packages, api

I am trying to learn about API wrappers (still have no clue as to how they are made) and was wondering, if I ever were to make any wrappers for APIs, how would I host them?

I have used APIs before for projects but have always wondered how these APIs are imported and from where they are imported? Are they hosted on privates websites or GitHub?

I was doing some research about the Scala API for Twitter and stumbled upon [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/twitter4s). I [see that the documentation](http://danielasfregola.github.io/twitter4s/6.1/api/com/danielasfregola/twitter4s/index.html) was made with Scaladoc but how exactly they host it on GitHub so that we could see their documentation? And how do the packages link even work?

Comment: I think you should start with understanding what a wrapper is: if I understand your context right then it's just code that makes it easier to use some, say, HTTP REST API in some specific programming language, without having to care about authentication and HTTP networking yourself. That said, this question is off-topic on Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are com.[username].[api]?

In my experience, this is typically a method of organization that allows a logical hierarchy of whatever you're organizing in addition to reducing the possibility of naming conflicts. Obviously, it emulates the way that domain names (as well as file systems) are set up (from a root [i.e. `com`] to more specific levels).

For instance, if developer A and developer B both create a module called `foo`, you would have `com.developerA.foo` and `com.developerB.foo`, rather than just `foo` and `foo` (which could cause a naming conflict if used at the same time). It is also easy to distinguish that the module `com.developerA.foo` belongs to developer A (along with e.g. `com.developerA.bar`) and `com.developerB.foo` belongs to developer B (along with e.g. `com.developerB.baz`).

In the case of the documentation in your link, each level is a separate HTML link to GitHub (though they could likely link to somewhere else as well).

> If I ever were to make any wrappers for APIs, how would I host them?

Unfortunately, it isn't clear to me what "hosting" means in this context. However, hosting requires a PC with some kind of server software that can be accessed by the public (whether you are allowing access to files for download or allowing users to directly interact with whatever you've built).

As an example, it is possible to use `git` and Apache Web Server to host something vaguely similar to GitHub (where you can make Git repository links or URL connections available to the public via Apache).

> I have always wondered how these APIs are imported and from where they are imported?

It isn't clear to me what the context of "imported" is here. But with web APIs broadly, you are generally contacting a program or script. But rather than typing commands at the command line, you put them in the form of a URL. The data you receive back is analogous to the output from a command line program as well, but transmitted to your browser (rather than a terminal).

With wrappers and web APIs, they often "wrap" URL calls. So if you use a function called e.g `sendMsg` in a wrapper for Twitter, the function itself is likely doing something similar to contacting e.g. `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/some_api_interface/sendmessage?msg=blahblahblah`(where Twitter then sends your message `blahblahblah`).

> Are they hosted on privates websites or GitHub?

The answer would likely be that both of these could be viable places to host something like this (again, depending on the software and your definition of "host").

> I was doing some research about the Scala API for Twitter and stumbled upon this GitHub repo. I see that the documentation was made with Scaladoc but how exactly do they host it on GitHub so that we could see their documentation?

As far as I am aware, [the documentation produced is normal HTML](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/generate.html) and thus can be hosted by any web server that can host HTML files.

> And how do the packages links even work?

Perhaps oversimplifying here, but a web server is used to serve the HTML document with the links. Large sites like GitHub have many layers when it comes to delivering files, so it probably isn't possible to give an accurate answer as to how the links themselves "work". But with standard `git`, there can be a CGI program that retrieves the files and delivers them to the browser, if the server doesn't simply make those files directly available via other means (direct links, `ftp`, other scripting, etc).

Comment: I'd say wrappers are not hosted at all. Sure, their _code repositories_ are hosted somewhere, like on GitHub. But the wrappers are just imported into one's project, just like any other library.